# Ember.js accessing model values from afterModel

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a Game model. Each game has multiple Cards.

```
App.GameRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('game', params.game_id);
    },
    afterModel: function (model) {
        var store, gameId, promises;

        store = this.get('store');
        gameId = model.get('id');

        promises = [
            store.find('card', { gameId: gameId })
        ];

        return Ember.RSVP.all(promises);
    }
});
```

When I go to a specific game, all related cards get successfully loaded.

In my template I want to loop over all cards. How can I do this?
I tried all possible variations of {{#each}} but nothing works.
Also, when I view the Ember Chrome Toolbar and look at the Data tab, all the cards are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the route:

```
App.GameRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            game: this.store.find('game', params.game_id),
            cards: this.store.find('cards', { gameId: params.game_id })
        });
    }
});
```

I can now loop over the cards this way:

```
{{#each card in Cards}}
    {{card.id}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: why capitalise **Cards?**