# Ember.js accessing model values in afterModel

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

There is a Question here [Ember.js accessing model values from afterModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944270/ember-js-accessing-model-values-from-aftermodel)

but it doesn't exlpain how to access the value in the afterModel hook. Can someone advise?

my model:

```
model: function () {

  return Ember.RSVP.hash({

    accounts: this.store.find('account').then(function (account) {
    })
  });
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read the documentation? The model is the first parameter passed to `afterModel`.

https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.13/classes/Route/methods/transitionTo?anchor=afterModel

On a slightly unrelated note, I wonder why you are returning `Ember.RSVP.hash` from the `model` hook. That makes the model (after being resolved) a hash containing a property `accounts`, which is presumably what you are interested in. That means every time you access the model you have to say `model.accounts`. Why not just return `this.find(...` itself, which would make the model itself the array of account instances which you could refer to directly as `model`?

Comment: We have several find's going.